# Flipping [UIImage] set in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two images that I want to switch between, lets call them fish and fisha. The UIImageView is called player, so the code is made as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var player: UIImageView!
var images: [UIImage] = []
images.append(UIImage(named: "fish")!)
images.append(UIImage(named: "fisha")!)
player.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth-px)/2, (screenHeight-py)/2, px, py)
player.animationImages = images
player.animationDuration = 0.7
player.startAnimating()
```

This all works fine. But now say i want to make a second UIImageView called player2, which should be the mirrored version of player.

Using this function:

```
func flipH(im:UIImage)->UIImage {
    var newOrient:UIImageOrientation
    switch im.imageOrientation {
    case .Up:
        newOrient = .UpMirrored
    case .UpMirrored:
        newOrient = .Up
    case .Down:
        newOrient = .DownMirrored
    case .DownMirrored:
        newOrient = .Down
    case .Left:
        newOrient = .RightMirrored
    case .LeftMirrored:
        newOrient = .Right
    case .Right:
        newOrient = .LeftMirrored
    case .RightMirrored:
        newOrient = .Left
    }
    return UIImage(CGImage: im.CGImage!, scale: im.scale, orientation: newOrient)
    }
```

Along with this modification of the code to make player2 i expect it to work properly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var player2: UIImageView!
var images: [UIImage] = []
images.append(flipH(UIImage(named: "fish")!))
images.append(flipH(UIImage(named: "fisha")!))
player2.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth-px)/2, (screenHeight-py)/2, px, py)
player2.animationImages = images
player2.animationDuration = 0.7
player2.startAnimating()
```

However, it doesnt. Player2 is identical to player. Does anyone have any idea why??

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `orientation` of a UIImage doesn't mean what you think it means. It isn't some sort of magical image-transformer. If you want to flip an image, *flip it* (i.e. draw it in a graphics context with a flipped CTM).

For example, here's an image displayed in an image view:

[image]

Here's the same image, flipped right-to-left, displayed in an image view:

[image]

The underlying code involves drawing the first image into a CTM-flipped graphics context to derive the second image.

Comment: Ah, is there no way to programmatically flip UIImages like I want?